# Deleting an untyped shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

I am working on wrapping a C++ library into a C bridge.

All objects, I’d like to maintain with shared_ptrs on the heap like:

```
void* makeFoo() {
  return new shared_ptr<void>(shared_ptr::make_shared<Foo>());
}
```

Can I use a generic destroy like this:

```
void destroy(void* p) {
  delete static_cast<shared_ptr<void>*> p;
}
```

Or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I assume you mean `delete static_cast<shared_ptr<void>*>(p)`?

Comment: Yes, fixed in the question now.

Comment: Well, it isn't. You also need a template parameter for `shared_ptr` in the first snippet. Please make sure that your code is actually syntactically valid and meaningful before posting.

Comment: No, not fixed yet...

Comment: Your last edit adds yet more invalid C++. Why do you keep dropping things randomly in `<>` brackets?

Comment: Your last edit completely changes the point ... it incorporates what I've mentioned in my answer. Yet you still didn't fix the glaring syntax issues in `destroy`.  Please don't make changes which change the point of your question.

Comment: Your answer is accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a two things at play here:

1. When you call `new SomeType()` ... then you need to call `delete pointer` where `pointer` has type `SomeType *` and points to the object allocated by that `new` expression. There are extensions to this rule with regards to base classes, but inheritance is not involved here, so we'll leave it at that.
2. `shared_ptr<Foo>` manages not only the `Foo` object, but also a "deleter" which knows how to destruct the `Foo` object.  When you construct one `shared_ptr` from another, then that deleter gets passed on.  This allows for "type erasure":

   ```cpp
   shared_ptr<Foo> typed = make_shared<Foo>();
   shared_ptr<void> erased = typed;
   ```

   Here, `erased` does no longer have compile time information about the type of the object it points to (that information was "erased"), but still has runtime information (the deleter) about the type of the object.

So to make this work, you need to make sure that you don't violate point 1 above; you need to `delete` the same type which you allocated with `new`: a `shared_ptr<void>`.  This `shared_ptr<void>` needs to be constructed from a `shared_ptr<Foo>` because then it has a deleter which knows how to destruct a `Foo`:

```cpp
void* makeFoo() {
  shared_ptr<Foo> with_type = make_shared<Foo>();
  shared_ptr<void> type_erased = with_type; // Just for illustration, merge with line below!
  return new shared_ptr<void>(type_erased);
}

void destroy(void * ptr) {
  shared_ptr<void> * original_ptr = ptr;
  delete original_ptr;
}
```

`makeFoo` returns a pointer to a `shared_ptr<void>`. Just with the type info stripped, i.e. as `void *`.

`destroy` assumes it is passed such a pointer. Its delete calls the destructor of `shared_ptr<void>`. Because the `shared_ptr<void>` has the deleter of the original `shared_ptr<Foo>`, it knows how to actually destruct the object (`Foo`).

---

Side note: OP's code changed quite a few times, but still has basic syntax errors. This is not valid C++!!

```
delete <shared_ptr<void>*> p;
```

Comment: Constructing a `shared_ptr<void>` is a good solution. The code in this example is a bit wasteful (what was the point of `type_erased`? Just pass `with_type` into the `new shared_ptr<void>(...)` expression) but otherwise this is a good suggestion.

Comment: Yes; I've made it verbose to show the steps: shared_ptr construction, shared_ptr type erasure, making it a dynamically allocated shared_ptr

Comment: Isn’t the equivalent to OP’s makeFoo?

Comment: no, because you have a pointer to a `shared_ptr<Foo>` ... but you need a pointer to a `shared_ptr<void>`

Comment: in `destroy()`, you still need to typecast the input `void*` before you can then `delete` it: `void destroy(void * ptr) { shared_ptr<void> * original_ptr = static_cast<shared_ptr<void>*>(ptr); delete original_ptr; }`

Answer (score 5):

The type of the argument to `delete` must match the actual type of the thing you're deleting (otherwise how would the right destructor be invoked, for example?), or at least be a base type in a polymorphic hierarchy so the destructor can be found virtually ([`[expr.delete]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3)).

So, no, you can't do that.

Comment: Sorry for not providing an alternative, but that's a much broader topic than your base question; perhaps someone else has time for that today!

Comment: shared_ptr maintains a deleter that is used for destructing the inner object. So your answer is wrong.

Comment: @user3612643 What shared_ptr maintains is irrelevant, because the `delete` statement triggering its destruction is fundamentally broken.

Comment: @user3612643 Have a read of [`[expr.delete]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3)

Comment: @user3612643 That's fascinating, but still irrelevant. The OP does not have a `shared_ptr<void>`, at all. Yet they are pretending to `delete` that they do. It _could_ form the basis of an alternative (and valid) solution though, which I encourage you to explore and write an answer about.

Comment: The link posted is not irrelevant. it's exactly the reason why this **does** work. see my answer.

Comment: @DanielJour Of course it's relevant. Your code correctly abides by the rule in that standard paragraph (by actually creating a `shared_ptr<void>`); the OP's code, does not. It's different code...

Comment: Yes; OP needs to make sure to actually return a pointer to a `shared_ptr<void>`

Comment: @DanielJour Right, which they didn't, which is why everybody is telling them that their code is broken.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica yes ... OP's code is more than a bit broken

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no such "generic delete".

Alternative solution: You can insert the `std::shared_ptr<void>` into a map, using the address of the dynamic object as key. The deallocation function can erase the shared pointer from the map.

Comment: Yep that can work nicely as long as the map stores `shared_ptr<void>`s

Comment: This is wrong. of course it works. shared_ptr has a deleter which remembers the type.

Comment: @DanielJour It is not wrong. Again, you missed the point, that no matter what `shared_ptr` does, if you pass `delete` a `T1*` that actually points to an unrelated `T2`, the program has undefined behaviour. Period. The reason the code in your answer is valid is because _you fixed that problem_ by passing a correct `T1*`, that points to a `T1`, to `delete`.

Comment: @user3612643 `So that basically means I need to wrap it into some structure that maintains a deleter` that structure is the shared pointer (to void, as clarified by LR).

Comment: I think this answer is wrong as it also illegally casts.

Comment: @user3612643 This answer does not cast at all. Conversion to `std::shared_ptr<void>` is implicit.

Comment: But if shared_ptr<void> is a proper subtype of shared_ptr<Foo>, then also the OP proposed solution will work. Because your answer and OP’s solution exploit the same property.

Comment: @user3612643 there is no solution in OP. I'd be surprised if it even compiled. There are no "subtype"s involved.

Comment: @user3612643 Why do you talk about yourself in the third person?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica why do you get personal?